# Need to loop over pandas series to find indices of variable

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe and a list. I would like to iterate over elements in the list and find their location in dataframe then store this to a new dataframe

```
my_list = ['1','2','3','4','5']
df1 = pd.DataFrame(my_list, columns=['Num'])
```

dataframe : **df1**

```
            Num
     0      1       
     1      2       
     2      3
     3      4
     4      5
```

dataframe : **df2**

```
        0        1      2       3         4
0       9        12     8       6         7
1       11       1      4       10        13
2       5        14     2       0         3
```

I've tried something similar to this but doesn't work

```
for x in my_list:
    i,j= np.array(np.where(df==x)).tolist()
    df2['X'] = df.append(i)
    df2['Y'] = df.append(j)
```

so looking for a result like this

dataframe : **df1** updated

```
            Num     X       Y
     0      1       1       1
     1      2       2       2
     2      3       2       4
     3      4       1       2
     4      5       2       0
```

any hints or ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to find the value in df2, why not just make df2 a flat dataframe.

```
df2 = pd.melt(df2)
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
df2.columns = ['X', 'Y', 'Num']
```

so now your df2 just looks like this:

```
Index   X   Y   Num
0       0   0   9
1       1   0   11
2       2   0   5
3       3   1   12
4       4   1   1
5       5   1   14
```

You can of course sort by Num and if you just want the values from your list you can further filter df2:

```
df2 = df2[df2.Num.isin(my_list)]
```